# How to get ruby mkmf to recognize a patched in function?

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems

I'm interested in using [ruby-prof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/) and specifically interested in the memory profiling aspect of it. I'm trying to use it for ruby 1.9.3-p484 specifically. I know it requires a patch, and have essentially applied [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/gcdata.patch) albeit modified for p484.

Ruby compiles/builds fine and my irb for the ruby environment has those functions defined on GC

```
irb(main):001:0> GC.malloc_allocations
=> 56769
irb(main):002:0> GC.malloc_allocated_size
=> 11939060
```

I then try to gem install ruby-prof (using the gem binary from my custom ruby) and it installs fine. However, the mkmf extconf it runs over refuses to recognize the patched in functions. Irb confirms this.

```
irb(main):004:0> have_func("rb_gc_malloc_allocations")
checking for rb_gc_malloc_allocations()... no
=> false
irb(main):005:0> have_func("rb_gc_malloc_allocated_size")
checking for rb_gc_malloc_allocated_size()... no
=> false
```

I know the [documentation for have_func](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/Object.html#method-i-have_func) says it checks the "common" (not sure what that means) header files first or any other header files you tell it to check. ruby-prof by default just checks the common headers (in their extconf.rb).

Unfortunately, I'm not too hot with C. Am I missing something with the patch? Do I need to put something in the ruby headers too? Some flags I need to pass to the gem install command so ruby-prof's extconf.rb finds the right function? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've figured this out finally (with some help from coworkers of course). It turns out that the function did need to be exposed as available in the ruby headers. The patch I posted in the question needed to be tweaked a bit to match what ruby-prof was expecting (and to expose the function in the headers).

I've put it up [here](https://gist.github.com/bubbadean123/9277839) in the hopes that it'll help out some future knowledge seeker.